# Cannot see POST array in response

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel, checkbox

First I have a list of checkboxes

```
@foreach ($extras as $extra)
    <span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn" value="{{ $extra->id }}" data-color="primary">
         {{ $extra->name.' - $'.$extra->amount}}
    </button>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extras[]" id="extras" class="hidden" />
    </span>
@endforeach
```

These buttons act as checkboxes. There is JS behind the scenes that takes the button value and adds it to the sibling checkbox value and marks it as checked. I know this works because I can see the `extras[]` in my console marked as checked and listed if I run `$("[name='extras[]']").serializeArray()`.

I have a function that POSTs the form data to a controller serverside that will do something with the data and send something back.

```
function updateTotals() {
    var url = "/reservation/updateTotals";
    //set hidden field that holds the selected property's name
    //$('#property_name').val($('#properties').text().trim());
    $.post(url, $("form").serializeArray())
        .done(function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
        })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("Error updating totals.");
    })
    .always(function() {
        //alert( "finished" );
    });
}
```

I have a route that links to the controller: 
`Route::post('reservation/updateTotals', 'ReservationController@updateTotals');`

And right now I am just testing with the Controller to get my array data:

```
public function updateTotals() {
    //get property
    $property = Property::findOrFail(Input::get('property_id'));

    //get extras
    return $extras = $_POST['extras'];

    //get discount
    $discount = Input::get('discount');
}
```

when I `return` just `$_POST['extras']` or `Input::get('extras')` I get nothing in my response. However, if I return `$_POST` or `Input::all()` I get back all of my **non-array* POST data. There is a field for `extras` but it is blank: `,"extras":"",` <-- from my Response

I have tried eliminating the button all together and just using checkboxes and still get the same result.

What am I missing here? What could be my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `Extras` as an array, with no values. In other words, `var Extras[];` Will declare an array, and give it the values `null;` and `null;` Try defining the checks as vairbles, and sending them to the `Extras` array, it's more efficient and supported.

Comment: Defining the checks as variables? Do you mean .each() through the checked and create a variable out of each one and push it all to an array?

Comment: @user2690363 that's exactly what I mean, I just worded it weird.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but setting my serialized array to a var before sending to `$.post()` made everything work (by that I mean the extras array is visible and usable in my controller and can be seen in the response). I have no idea why, but that definitely is the case for me.

```
function updateTotals() {
    var data = $('form').serializeArray();
    var url = "/reservation/updateTotals";

    $.post(url, data)
        .done(function(data) {
            //do something
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("Error updating totals.");
    })
    .always(function() {
        //alert( "finished" );
    });
}
```